# Show that the function $d_p(x,y):\Bbb{Q}\to \Bbb{R}_+$ is a metric function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-number-theory

Show that the function $d_p(x,y):\Bbb{Q}\to \Bbb{R}_+$, $p$ prime, defined as follows:

*If $x=y$, $d_p(x,y)=0$.

*If $x\ne y$, setting  $x-y={u\cdot p^b\over v \cdot p^a}$ such that $(u,p)=(v,p)=1$, define $d_p(x,y)=p^{a-b}$.

It was clear to me why non-negativity and Symmetry hold, but the Triangle Inequality is where I am stuck. There is a more known $p$ metric defined over the integers but I am afraid it doesn't contribute much in that case. I have been looking at $x,y,z\in \Bbb{Q}$, setting $$x-y={u\over v}\cdot {p^b\over p^a}, x-z={m\over n}\cdot {p^d\over p^c},  z-y={r\over s}\cdot {p^f\over p^e}$$.

$$x-y=x-z+z-y={m\over n}\cdot {p^d\over p^c}+{r\over s}\cdot {p^f\over p^e}={ms\cdot p^{c+d}+rn\cdot p^{f+e}\over sn\cdot p^{c+e}}={\alpha\cdot p^{\min(c+d,f+e)}\over\beta\cdot p^{c+e}}$$, but I can't bring myself to understanding whether or not $\alpha$ is co-prime to $p$ and I can't seem to see how applying the distance over $x,y$ using the expression above can get me any further. I would really appreciate it if you could help me sort things out.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: $p$ is a prime. I am sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: To show that $p$ is coprime to $\alpha$, you can assume to the contrary that $p$ divides $\alpha$ and conclude (using primality) that $p$ would divide $m$, $r$, $s$, or $n$ (a contradiction).  You'd have to do the same with $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for that. Why would I have to do the same for $\beta=sn$? That is how it was defined and it should be clear it is coprime to $p$, shouldn't it? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know how clear it is.  It's worth mentioning at least.

Comment: I agree with that.